# C++ Primer Plus Chapter 2 Exercise 3

Tags: c++

I have started to teach myself C++ via "C++ Primer Plus sixth edition." For the most part I understand the basics of everything which I have read so far. But when trying to do the exercises, I am start to draw blanks and second question myself. The first two exercises I did well, but I am in need of assistance on the third.

The exercise states:

> Write a C++ program that uses three user-defined functions (counting
>   main() as one) and produces the following:

```
Three blind mice.
Three blind mice.  
See how they run.  
See how they run.
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int blind(int);
int run(int);
int main() {
   using namespace std;

   int n;
   cin >> n;
   cout << "Three blind mice." << n << endl;
   int s;
   cin >> s;
   cout << "See how they run." << s << endl;


   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
int blind(int n) {
   using namespace std;

   return 2 * n;
}
int run(int s) {
   using namespace std;

   cout << "See how they run.";
   return 2 * s;

}
```

I was hoping to have it built in such a way, that when I typed in a number it would reply with the message multiplied by the number I typed. But maybe that is too complex for what they are asking? And I do not have it built correctly either.

Anyways, if you could please help me out, I would be extremely grateful!
~P. Suedo

Comment: I think you are making this more complicated than necessary. If I were to do the assignment, I would write one function to print out each sentence and then call these functions from `main`.

Comment: On `adding 4 spaces`, tell your IDE to replace tabs with spaces.  It will save you a ton of headaches later.  What IDE are you using?

Comment: @zero298 let's not start a tabs v spaces argument...

Comment: @paulrehkugler: For posting here at SO, it is preferred to use spaces instead of tabs. In your own code editor, you can exercise your choice. When posting code here, spaces instead of tabs make code easier to format and reduces indent levels and horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @Code-Guru Could you give me an example on how this works? I have tried to do this, but my mind goes blank when errors pop up.

Comment: @Psuedo SO is a great place to ask about specific compiler errors when you don't know what they mean. Just be sure to include the code that causes the error as well as the exact error message.

Comment: @Psuedo what do you mean by `when I typed in a number it would reply with the message multiplied by the number I typed` you are printing strings, you can't multiply a string by a number.  Do you mean you want printed instead `Six blind mice` for `blind(2)`?  Because if that is the case, that will take a lot more effort as C++ doesn't really understand what the literal `"Three"` means with respect to being `3` and as such cannot multiply it.

Comment: @zero298 I was trying to use integers, in such a way, that it would reply with the "cout" messages appearing in the numeric value which I inputted. It sounds really dumb, but that is one of the ways which I though the lesson wanted me to create the lines. I apologize for any confusion. I need to freshen up on this lesson before moving ahead. Thank you for your help. *smiley face*

Comment: @paulrehkugler Adding to what Ken White said...the #1 cause of mangled code blocks at SO is copying code formatted with tabs. There's no debate, tab-formatted code is rendered poorly at SO. If any changes need to be made, it's a nightmare to edit. Sometimes the entire first level of indentation is flattened, and often the indentation is uneven. Probably the most common edit I've found myself making is copying tabbed code in to my code editor, replacing the tabs with spaces, and copying it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible function can be as simple as

```
void threeBlindMice() {
    cout << "Three blind mice." << endl;
}
```

I leave it to you to figure out another function and how to use both functions from main.

Comment: Thank you! I will now try to figure out the rest and make sure to have it chiseled in my head. *smiley*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  You pose that your expected output should be:

```
Three blind mice.
Three blind mice.  
See how they run.  
See how they run.
```

So the simplest program to get that output would be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void blind() {
   cout << "Three blind mice." << endl;
}
void run() {
   cout << "See how they run." << endl;
}
int main() {

   blind();
   blind();
   run();
   run();

   return 0;
}
```

I don't mean to be asking more questions from an answer, but if there is more to what you are asking, please let me know.  You don't need any `cin` or anything like that.  Additionally, considering your example, you can hoist up your call to `using namespace std;` so that you don't have to include it in each function.

Also, unless your functions `blind()` and `run()` rely on some state that hasn't been defined yet, (which they don't in this case) you don't need to declare them before `main()` and then define them below.  You can just declare and define them at the top before `main()`

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do it a more complex matter, which is why I was using cin. My apologies for being unclear, I had been at this problem for too long and was not very cognitive when it came to asking the question. Both yours and Guru helped me out a-lot. Thanks. *smiley*

Answer (score 0):

There are two websites which provide solutions to most of the programming exercises found in this book. The websites are: [www.ignatkov.net](http://www.ignatkov.net/category/cppprimerplus/) & [http://github.com](https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/CxxPrimerPlus). I think they are very useful in providing a method to check your solutions to the exercises alongside the 'stack overflow website'